# Website Tablet Check Out Field Issue

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, html, responsive, code

So on my website of http://www.camerabeanbags.co.uk/checkout/ if you set the browser to 768px wide the 'phone' and 'e-mail address' fields can not be clicked in for text to me typed in.

These work fine on any resolution below 768px and anything after 992px wide.

I have looked at the CSS and tried amending this to get them to both work but haven't had much look.

If you add an item to the basket... then go to check out... set the screen at 768px or higher but below 992px you will see what I mean. Any ideas on what could be causing this and how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything works fine for me on 800px.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code below has fixed the issue

```
 .woocommerce-billing-fields__field-      wrapper:after {
 clear: both;
 display: table;
 content: '';
 }
```

Thanks